# How can I use multiple probabilities to determine a final result?

Tags: probability

I am trying to use a variety of metrics in to determine who would win a game of rugby.
Using historical data I have determined that:

1. A team with a higher completion rate wins 63% of the time,
2. A team with the higher possession wins 71% of the time
3. A team with the higher running metres wins 88% of the time.

I then compare the teams averages over the season for the upcoming round. Can I combine the 3 metrics above to make a probability of each team winning (with the total probability to equal 1)?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a Venn diagram?

Comment: Modeling things in the real world generally means coming up with a model and then testing it against the data.  Take a portion of the data and find the "best" blend of your metrics.  Then see if your blend works for the rest of the data. Be prepared for lots of failures.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @lulu.  One of the complications that you face is that the individual metrics are **not** independent events.  In the classic Bayes Theorem question of two *independent* weather forecasters: A who is right $(0.8)$ of the time and B who is right $(0.9)$ of the time, suppose that one morning A and B disagree.  In order to apply Bayes theorem, to see the chances that [A is right - B is wrong], you have to make an assumption similar to [A-right,B-Wrong = $(0.8) \times (0.1)$] and [A-wrong, B-right = $(0.2) \times (0.1)$].  ...see next comment

Comment: In fact, in reality this is questionable.  On the one hand, there must be *some* independence, since you are given that they disagree.  On the other hand, they are probably both examining cloud formations, among other things.  You have similar considerations/difficulties with respect to the metrics that you mention.  How independent are the metrics from each other?

Comment: @user2661923 Agreed, thats the part I'm finding difficult as they are somewhat independent by overall they're part of the same game so a team with higher possession is likely to have a higher completion rate. I was weighing up whether to use the multiplication rule but as the opposite team will have to be 1 - the probability of team A winning it doesn't work.

Comment: As a former professional sports bettor, I can tell you what professional sports bettors due.  They eyeball it, relying **extremely** heavily on intuition, and they consider each metric separately.  For example, to consider the NFL, if you have a team with a good passing game but only a fair running game, then for their upcoming opponent, what is the matchup like?  If the opponent has an excellent pass rush, but is only so-so against the run, then the team with the excellent passing game matches up poorly against the opponent.

Comment: In professional sports betting, it is generally seat-of-the-pants decisions, with the understanding that (metaphorically), your caboose is a high-speed-computer.  This is very similar to professional poker.  Probably about 98% of people who attempt professional sports betting will not get rich in the long run, in the same way that the vast majority of professional baseball players in double-A or triple-A will not have a long-term major league career.  I strongly advise **against** attempting to predict outcomes via a mathematical consideration of metrics.

Comment: I did see the movie *Moneyball* with Brad Pitt (about major league baseball).  But remember, 162 games is a long season.  They weren't trying to predict the outcome of any single game, but rather how many wins the team would have at the end of the season.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @user2661923 Yeah I've done it up so that I can compare the season averages for each statistic of the two teams to playing, I was hoping there was a way to combine them together using a type of weighted average for probability but I guess not.